# Extract Username from a instagram image link

Tags: php

I am using a php script to extract data from a instagram IMAGE link.When user enters a image link this script shows his media ID and his account ID.What i want to extract now is the username of the owner of the pic from the link

here is the pregmatch my friend made for me

```
preg_match('~"instapp:owner_user_id" content="([^"]*)"~', $html, $match);
$title = $match[1];
preg_match('~"al:ios:url"\s+content="[^\d"]*(\d+)"~', $html, $test);
$title1 = $test[1];
```

Can anyone help me extract username from lets say this link view-source:https://www.instagram.com/p/BRVyb-fjcLA/

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BRVyb-fjcLA/';
function usernameFromInstgramLink($url){
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('/\(@([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\)/', $html, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
$username = usernameFromInstgramLink($url);
```